# Rider - keep anonymous function block argument on same line as function call

Tags: c#, rider

I've tried all settings I could find relating to this issue in the rider settings. I would really like the start of the anonymous function block argument to be on the same line as the function I'm passing it to, so the content of the anonymous function is only indented once.

Desired styling:

```
EditorGuiBuilder.Horizontal(() => {
    EditorGUILayout.TextField("text");
    EditorGUILayout.TextField("text");
});
```

Result after formatting:

```
EditorGuiBuilder.Horizontal(
    () => {
        EditorGUILayout.TextField("text");
        EditorGUILayout.TextField("text");
    });
```

Is there an existing setting that will achieve this formatting?

**Edit:**

Weirdly enough the block stays on the same line if there is another argument

```
EditorGuiBuilder.Grid(iconsPerRow, () => {
    EditorGUILayout.TextField("text");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These settings should work (File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | C#):

1. On "Braces Layout" tab change "Anonymous method declaration" to "At
   end of line"
2. On "Line Breaks and Wrapping" tab uncheck "Prefer wrap
   before "(" in invocation" and "Prefer wrap before ")" in invocation"